# Android progressive resource sound playback

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to use both progressive and cached sound files in my android app. Tthe soundpool works great for preloading small files, but obviously sometimes you need to play a 15-30sec sound file. I don't want to preload those (and can't due to memory constraints), but i'm at a loss to discover how to progressively stream resource sounds. Every tutorial about progressive sound streaming is for HTTP streams.

The sounds are in /res/raw/ and are oggs.

How do i progressively stream local resource sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's been some time from this question's being asked, i figure i'll mark it as answered with the method i went with.

I decided to make a jni wrapper over libvorbis and include the library with the app so that it can stream sounds using native libvorbis code. It's a pain, and it really shouldn't be necessary with all the decoding capability that android has, but i can't find any convenience methods.

So, for future googlers, sorry for the bad news.